# Do you need to call 'endDialog' for every 'beginDialog' in Microsoft Bot Framework ? When should one call 'endDialog'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework

EDIT:

In going through the source code, I found the following in `botbuilder.d.ts`.  It would seem that in waterfalls you don't need to call `endDialog` explicitly?

```
/* You can terminate a waterfall early by either falling through every step of the waterfall using
 * calls to `skip()` or simply not starting another prompt or dialog.
 *
 * __note:__ Waterfalls have a hidden last step which will automatically end the current dialog if
 * if you call a prompt or dialog from the last step. This is useful where you have a deep stack of
 * dialogs and want a call to [session.endDialog()](/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.session.html#enddialog)
 * from the last child on the stack to end the entire stack. The close of the last child will trigger
 * all of its parents to move to this hidden step which will cascade the close all the way up the stack.
 * This is typically a desired behavior but if you want to avoid it or stop it somewhere in the
 * middle you'll need to add a step to the end of your waterfall that either does nothing or calls
 * something like [session.send()](/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.session.html#send)
 * which isn't going to advance the waterfall forward.
 * @example
 * <pre><code>
 * var bot = new builder.BotConnectorBot();
 * bot.add('/', [
 *     function (session) {
 *         builder.Prompts.text(session, "Hi! What's your name?");
 *     },
 *     function (session, results) {
 *         if (results && results.response) {
 *             // User answered question.
 *             session.send("Hello %s.", results.response);
 *         } else {
 *             // User said never mind.
 *             session.send("OK. Goodbye.");
 *         }
 *     }
 * ]);
 * </code></pre>
 */
```

I'm learning the MS Bot Framework version 3 -- that's the version they're working with here.

I follow the concept of how waterfalls work (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-dialog-manage-conversation-flow?view=azure-bot-service-3.0), but one thing I don't understand is what role `endDialog` plays.

For instance, in the code we are working with, there are a bunch of separate dialogs which all have the form

```
module.exports = function showTickets() {
    this.bot.dialog('/showAllTickets', [
        async function showAllTicketsFn(session, args, next) {
            this.beginDialog.bind(this, '/showTickets')(session, args, next);
        }.bind(this)
    ]);
};
```

Basically one dialog loading another (with some other code in between, like setting data in the data store).  Nowhere is `endDialog` called.  But in the example from the MS tutorial, every waterfall ends with some form of `endDialog` (`endDialog` or `endDialogWithResults`, etc).

Does every dialog 'opened' with `beginDialog` automatically 'close' itself when its waterfall is done, that is, when the functions that are passed in the array to `bot.dialog` are run through?  (in the code above, the waterfall is only one step).

When does one need to call `endDialog` explicitly?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really, the documentation should say that you ***should*** end the dialog, not that you ***must***. Waterfalls will end automatically if you don't call `EndDialog` explicitly. It's meant to be more of a built-in safety mechanism, to help avoid a user get stuck, forgetting to call enddialog after getting result. But there are cases where it is ok not add an explicit `EndDialog` call. You can find more in waterfall [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-V3/blob/master/Node/core/lib/dialogs/WaterfallDialog.js).

One valid use case is where a dialog call's a waterfall that simply decides which dialog it wants to branch to. Once its branched to a given dialog there's no reason to add a step which ends after that dialog ends.

But likely, even in that case, it's more efficient to just use `ReplaceDialog` to replace yourself with the dialog you're branching to.

Answer (score 1):

Hey was wondering this myself and found this from MS

> A dialog that is created using a waterfall must be explicitly ended, otherwise the bot will repeat the waterfall indefinitely. You can end a waterfall by using one of the following methods:
>
> session.endDialog: Use this method to end the waterfall if there is no data to return to the calling dialog.
>
> session.endDialogWithResult: Use this method to end the waterfall if there is data to return to the calling dialog. The response argument that is returned can be a JSON object or any JavaScript primitive data type.

[Bot Framework Waterfall End Dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-dialog-waterfall?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#end-a-waterfall)

if you want to end all the dialogs and stop the conversation you can use the `endConversationAction` trigger with an optional message/object

```
this.bot.dialog('/showAllTickets', [
    async function showAllTicketsFn(session, args, next) {
        this.beginDialog.bind(this, '/showTickets')(session, args, next);
        session.endConversation();
    }.bind(this)
]);
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is true...see my edit to my original post above.  I am confused at this point, since what you've referenced seems to be different than the comments in the source code above.

Comment: Hmm that does seem to contradict the official guidance from MS. Will look into and maybe we can get a definite answer from someone who works on the framework